# Firebase multiple API calls?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

after message has been stored to messege node, i want to take that messge key and store it under user messege node. But after messege api is called, usermessege reference never gets called. Is there a work around, i tried a completion block that didnt work.

```
 @objc func didTapPost (){
    print("sending messge")
    
    let messegeRef = Database.database().reference().child("Messeges")
    let userMessegeRef = Database.database().reference().child("UserMessege")
    
    guard let messgeText = messegeTextField.text else {return}
    guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
    guard let user  = self.user else {return}

    
    
    let messegeNodeRef = messegeRef.childByAutoId()


    let creationDate  = Int(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)

    let newMessege = ["creationDate": creationDate,
                      "fromId": user.userId,
                      "toId": currentUser,
                      "messegeText": messgeText] as [String : Any]
     
   messegeNodeRef.setValue(newMessege)

   //For some reason these two api calls below wont run      userMessegeRef.child(currentUser).child(user.userId).updateChildValues([messegeNodeRef.key: 1])
    userMessegeRef.child(user.userId).child(currentUser).updateChildValues([messegeNodeRef.key: 1])

    messegeTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    messegeTextField.text = nil
   }
```

Comment: after message has been stored to messege node, i want to take that messge key and store it under user messege node. But after messege api is called, usermessege reference never gets called. Is there a work around, i tried a completion block that didnt work.

Comment: I added your comment to the question, but please do so yourself in the future (there's an `edit` link right under your question) to prevent getting downvoted.

Comment: " i tried a completion block that didnt work." Please edit your question to show what you tried, what you expected the result to be, and what the result was instead.